# Cors Error After adding window authentication in .NET Core 3.1

Tags: api, asp.net-core, cors

Wep API was working fine but after adding authentication middleware it starts to throw CORS error below is startup.cs code

Looked everwhere in google but nothing seems to work please provide me the right direction.

```
    public class Startup
    {
        readonly string MyAllowedSpecificOrigins = "_myAllowedSpecificOrigins";
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }


        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddCors(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy(name: MyAllowedSpecificOrigins,
                                  builder =>
                                  {
                                      builder
                                      .AllowAnyOrigin()
                                      .AllowAnyHeader()
                                      .AllowAnyMethod();
                                  });
            });
            services.AddTransient<IJobRepository, JobRepository>();
            services.AddSingleton<IConfiguration>(Configuration);
            services.AddControllers();
            services.AddAuthentication(NegotiateDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddNegotiate();
        }


        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }

            ///app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseRouting();
            app.UseCors(MyAllowedSpecificOrigins);
            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I suggest you could firstly add .AllowCredentials() and make sure client s set XMLHttpRequest.withCredentials to true . Details, you could refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-5.0#credentials-in-cross-origin-requests).

Comment: I'm glad this solution fix your issue. I will write a reply. Please mark it as answer, so other folks who faces the same issue could find the answer more easily. Thank you.

Comment: one more thing i am getting the same cors errors when i have included headers along credential include in my post request .like the below                                                                                     headers: {
                    "Content-Type": "application/json",
                },
                credentials: 'include',

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your description, I suggest you could firstly add `.AllowCredentials()` and make sure client s set XMLHttpRequest.withCredentials to true.

Credentials require special handling in a CORS request. By default, the browser doesn't send credentials with a cross-origin request. Credentials include cookies and HTTP authentication schemes. To send credentials with a cross-origin request, the client must set XMLHttpRequest.withCredentials to true.

More details, you could refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-5.0#credentials-in-cross-origin-requests).